# No keyReleaseEvent when QT context menu is displayed

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm using QT4 and I created a QGLWidget in which I want to implement a right-click context menu. I want the context menu to appear only when the right-mouse button is clicked and the CTRL key is pressed down.

I tried implementing this by setting a control flag when the CTRL key is pressed, and then clearing it when the CTRL key is released (via a `keyReleaseEvent`). The problem is that I don't receive a `keyReleaseEvent` when the context menu is up (not just CTRL, no key release at all).

For example: I hold down CTRL, click the right mouse button, and then the context menu appears (still holding CTRL). Without selecting anything in the menu, I release the CTRL key, but my program does not receive a `keyPressEvent`. Therefore my flag never gets cleared, and the next time the user right clicks (even without holding control) the context menu will appear.

Why don't I receive a `keyPressEvent` when a context menu is present?

I'm using QT 4.8 (C++) and tested this on both Windows and Linux with the same result.

Comment: Are you opening the context menu via contextMenuEvent, or via keyPressEvent?

Comment: And just to clarify, you want releasing CTRL to cause the context menu to disappear?

Comment: No, I'm opening it directly via exec during a mouse press event, and I want to leave it open after CTRL is released. It should close when something is selected or clicked elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the why part, Qt sends key events to the widget which has keyboard focus or is explicitly grabbing the keyboard (with `QWidget::grabKeyBoard()`), since the context menu is that widget at the time you release the key, it receives the key release event.

Comment: I knew something like Anthony's answer would be the way to go, but I posted this mostly because of the why. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to handle this situation is to just check whether or not CTRL was held down when you open the context menu. That way you avoid these issues, and don't have to keep track of that flag. Try this:

```
void DerivedClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton && event->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier))
    {
        // Open the context menu.
    }
    else
    {
        BaseClass::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

EDIT: That's Qt::ControlModifier, not Qt::CtrlModifier.